# Adding a image upload option to a form on a jsp page and adding to a MySQL database table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, tomcat7

I am using a JSP page to add information through tomcat to a MySQL database which is working. I would like to add a user profile picture upload function to the form. Can I save this image to the same database entry? How will do I go about adding a browse function to the form to select the image and persist it with the rest of the data?

Form from My Jsp:

```
<h2>Signup Details</h2>
        <form name="actionForm" action="RegistrationServlet" method ="post">
        <br/>Name:<input type="text" name="name">
        <br/>Address:<input type="text" name="address1">
        <br/><input type="text" name="address2">
        <br/>County:<input type="text" name="county">
        <br/>Telephone:<input type="text" name="phone">
        <br/>Email:<input type="text" name="email">
        <br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password">

        <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Registration Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
        System.out.println("In the registration Servlet");
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        user.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        user.setTelephone(request.getParameter("phone"));
        user.setCounty(request.getParameter("county"));
        user.setAddress1(request.getParameter("address1"));
        user.setAddress2(request.getParameter("address2"));
        RegisterUser.addUser(user);
        response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");        
    } catch (Throwable exc)
    {
        System.out.println(exc);
    }
```

Comment: If you will use browse then your request will become multipart request and you should have blob as field in database.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

Comment: its not good idea to store image in database. A wise practice would be to get path of image and store the path to database.